# MYSQL update query php

Tags: php, database, mysql

I am trying to use an update query to change values held in a database, the new values I am trying to store are held in php variables. I'm not sure what it is I'm doing wrong.

> mysql_query("UPDATE user SET
>   status='full' WHERE user_id =
>   '$user_id'")or die(mysql_error());

here is the error message

> Duplicate entry '91317691' for key 1

thanks in advance

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? Are you 100% sure there exists a user record with that ID? What does `$user_id` contain?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the type of error that happens. Maybe post the text of the mysql_error().

Comment: Please also add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE user`. Are you absolutely sure that the query you've posted is causing this "Duplicate entry" error?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question at all but take a look at http://www.woyano.com/jv/ezsql I like I think it helps. It is the library that Wordpress leverages for their transactions.

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is a duplication in unique key. Am supposing you are using unique on `(user_id, status)` and `status` is of type `enum`, if that the case, you might already be having an entry matching the one you are trying to update.

```
| user_id | status |
| 1234    | full   |
| 1234    | none   |
```

if thats not the case, posting schema would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your user_id field is an integer. Putting '' around it will break things

try it without the quotes

```
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET status='full' WHERE user_id = $user_id")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: MySQL automagically casts something like `'12'` to an integer if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

apologies, I realized the problem was caused elsewhere in my php script, but I have resolved it.

thanks for your guidance

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change

...  '" + $user_id + "'" ...

put closing double quote " after your single, then add your $user_id, then add the final closing "'" (double quote, single quote, double quote )

Additionally, if you don't have control of the $user_id variable, you could be open to SQL-injection attacks